# syscall GetLastError() doesn't return error

Tags: c++, winapi, go

In golang `syscall.GetLastError()` doesn't return the last error. See the following example

```
if handle := _OpenSCManager(machineNamePtr, databaseNamePtr, desiredAccess); handle == nil {
    if err := syscall.GetLastError(); err != nil {
        return InvalidServiceDatabaseHandleHandle, ServiceErrno(err.(syscall.Errno))
    }
}
```

`err` is always `nil`. Assume `machineNamePtr` is a non exsiting machine. Tested the same code with c++ and `GetLastError()` throws `RPC server is not available`. So why not on `go`?

EDIT

_OpenSCManager is generated with `go generate`.
`//sys _OpenSCManager(machineName *uint16, databaseName *uint16, desiredAcces ServiceAccessRight) (handle ServiceDatabaseHandle) = advapi32.OpenSCManagerW`

```
func _OpenSCManager(machineName *uint16, databaseName *uint16, desiredAcces ServiceAccessRight) (handle ServiceDatabaseHandle) {
r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(procOpenSCManagerW.Addr(), 3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(machineName)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(databaseName)), uintptr(desiredAcces))
handle = ServiceDatabaseHandle(r0)
return
```

}

Comment: It depends on your implementation of `_OpenSCManager`. Does that only returns a `handle` if it succeeds? Then you will never get an error here.

Comment: btw. in go when you want something private to the package you start the name with a lowercase instead of a underscore. `openSCManager` instead of `_OpenSCManager`.

Comment: Yes, it only returns a `handle`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms684323(v=vs.85).aspx). Is this `go` specific, because on native c++ i get the last error

Comment: Shouldn't the flow then be  1. make call 2. have handle? -> yes -> do stuff 3. have handle? -> no -> getlasterror and handle that ?

Comment: That's what i do. It's only a snippet to see if i get an error.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I did not notice the `== nil` in the handle test. Maybe then your `_OpenSCManager` always returns a handle whether it succeeds or not?

Comment: Is `err != nil` correct check that integer value is not 0?

Comment: And; Is there any threading in the `_OpenSCManager` function? `GetLastError` only returns the error for the current thread.

Comment: @VTT err is of type `error` and therefore not an int. https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L139

Comment: @RickyA I thought this code is supposed to call [`::GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) and inspect the value returned (which is integer).

Comment: That's what i think, that these `syscall` functions are running in another thread. I just want to know wheter it is so. So i have to return an general error.

Comment: If _OpenSCManager is written by you, can you please share it here!? It looks like golang is calling Windows functions itself and thus resetting the last error before you call your GetLastError. In web pages I saw the pattern to return a handle and the last error from functions. Maybe this would help in your case.

Comment: I would debug this by first removing the `if handle == nil` clause and always call 'GetLastError` and see if and what error it returns.

Comment: Well first that `syscall.Syscall` code is ignoring the error return (`r0,_,_`). That is always a bad idea. https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Syscall

Comment: Usually for this sort of interop, the framework calls `GetLastError` and captures the value internally immediately after the API call returns. Like the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` mechanism in .net p/invoke. Is that what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

So finally i've got this working. First i have tried to return an error variable with the following signature `//sys _OpenSCManager(machineName *uint16, databaseName *uint16, desiredAcces ServiceAccessRight) (handle ServiceDatabaseHandle, lasterror error) = advapi32.OpenSCManagerW`. But `go generate` throws always `Only last windows error is allowed as second return value...`. But if you change it to `//sys ... (handle ServiceDatabaseHandle, err error) =  advapi32.OpenSCManagerW` it successfully generates the code. So you explicit have to write `err error`. Someone knows why? So now the function looks like

```
func _OpenSCManager(machineName *uint16, databaseName *uint16, desiredAcces ServiceAccessRight) (handle ServiceDatabaseHandle, err error) {
r0, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procOpenSCManagerW.Addr(), 3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(machineName)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(databaseName)), uintptr(desiredAcces))
handle = ServiceDatabaseHandle(r0)
if handle == 0 {
    if e1 != 0 {
        err = errnoErr(e1)
    } else {
        err = syscall.EINVAL
    }
}
return
}
```

and it returns an error. So there is no need to call `GetLastError()`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the `syscall.Syscall()` on Windows automatically *and atomically* calls `GetLastError()` after the actual syscall finishes. That should be understandable once you consider that as soon as a goroutine exits from a syscall, the Go runtime scheduler is free to preempt it and run another goroutine on the very thread *the just-preempted goroutine had just been running on.*

Since `GetLastError()` accesses per-thread state, if the second goroutine makes another syscall, it would likely thrash that last error value, so in the context of Go, each syscall should be accompanied with the following call to `GetLastError()` done in the context of a single syscall invocation — as seen from the Go side.